# Material UI -Autocomplete how to get event.type or an extra attribute name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, material-ui

I am creating a handler to process user input. According to documentation I am using onUpdateInput to get the value which is selected but how do I assign a name and get event.type from 
`<Autocomplete name="mystate ..?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­`

I have  a handler which can then do something like this

```
autochangehandler(event){
            const target = event.type;
            const value =  target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
            const name = event.name;
```

I get target undefined because onUserinput does not return event directly it returns the chosen string. Link to all properties: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete

In short I have multiple inputs and in my handler I would like to check if it's a checkbox or autocomplete or some other field. After that I would like to setState corresponding to the field name that invoked it !

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need this? And why you check for the target being a checkbox?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have multiple inputs so my handler need to check if its an autocomplete, input or checkbox and then perform Setstate.

Comment: Then just check if target is a string first, then move on to the checkbox check.

Comment: Event. target is undefined. Materialpasses it's own custom values as event

Answer (score 0):

I just moved to https://ant.design/. Provides way more resources to work with. For my needs this library is awesome. I would encourage people to try it out.